# Do we use the structure "give something away" when talking about a person giving something to just one person?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

We often use "**give away**" when we say a person gives something to many as a gift, rather than just one person.

For example, *the teacher gave away candies to his students*.

Can we say "*the teacher gave away the candy to Mary*" (just 1 person, not many people)?

Comment: "Giving away" has a focus on the thing going away - it lightly implies that part of the action is about getting rid of the object. So for example, I might give away old clothes I don't wear anymore or food I'm not going to eat - it benefits me to get rid of these things and hopefully also benefits the person I'm giving them to. But if I purchased or made something with the purpose of it being a gift, I would "give the item" and not use the word away.

Comment: And 'give away' is usually used when the recipient isn't mentioned. _The teacher gave candies to his students_ (or _gave out_ (distributed)).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. It doesn't sound right.

Other thoughts: If you keep the structure but switch the word order. Changing your last sentence to this: '*the teacher **gave** the candy **away** to Mark*', it sounds a little better but still it misses the mark.

Even with multiple subjects the **away** part feels off. For the phrase 'give-away', it makes sense to keep the structure when using as a noun but when using as a verb, drop the away.